# Xamarin.iOS: Could not find the main bundle in the app ([NSBundle mainBundle] returned nil)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin but I'm transferred to a mobile team in my company to help out. Our project is Shared App Project with iOS and Android. To cut the story short I am working on iOS side and when I try to debug on device I'm getting this message:
Xamarin.iOS: Could not find the main bundle in the app ([NSBundle mainBundle] returned nil)
Everything works on simulator. I have the provisioning setup correctly and my device is registered (with few others). Not sure if anyone saw this message before. Any help would be appreciated.
Forgot to mention, the app builds just fine and deploys to device but I only see splash screen for a second and the app disappears 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your App.csproj file try to change your assembly name 
from

```
<AssemblyName>My.App</AssemblyName>
```

to

```
<AssemblyName>MyApp</AssemblyName>
```

If you use Xamarin Studio, double-click on your *iOS startup module*, go to *Output*.
[image]

Make sure that the name doesn't contain dot symbols. It appears that iOS treats dots as part of a bundle name or something like that.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue